# Nginx reverse proxy to django application, images styles are not showing

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, nginx

Hello i have a complete django app which I'll be hosting on aws ec2 with gunicorn and nginx. But when I run the app with gunicorn or python3 my app runs and shows all images with the css and styles. But whenever I try to serve my django app with nginx by proxy_pass the image or style or anything on static folder could not be accessed. my error log shows permission issue. But I have set the app with user and group both nginx. but nothing is showing.

- nginx conf on nginx.conf

```sh
http {
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile            on;
    tcp_nopush          on;
    tcp_nodelay         on;
    keepalive_timeout   65;
    types_hash_max_size 4096;

    include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type        application/octet-stream;
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

    server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;

    root /home/ec2-user/sites/softopark-django-cms;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/example.com.access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/example.com.error.log;
    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html/softopark-django-cms/static/;
    }
    location /media/  {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html/softopark-django-cms/media/;
    }
    location / {
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:8000/;
    }

    }
```

- my gunicorn service file

```sh
[Unit]
Description=test
After=network.target

[Service]
User=nginx
Group=nginx
WorkingDirectory=/usr/share/nginx/html/softopark-django-cms
Environment="/home/ec2-user/Env/cms5-XkwMz5k7/bin"
ExecStart=/home/ec2-user/Env/cms5-XkwMz5k7/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 cms_project.wsgi

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

- can anyone help me with this?

I need to host my django app on aws but with nginx I'm not being able to do it. Please help.

Comment: Django has nothing to do with serving static content directly through ngnix, you should write https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and include traceback

Answer (score 0):

Well, I didn't find any specific answer to this but I fixed it after running **`collectstatic`** command.

One thing, I missed that whenever we create any Django projects and at the time of deploying to another place we need to run **`python manage.py collectstatic`** so that our app can detect the static files and update their path. So I updated the codebase and deployed it on the server the but didn't used collectstatic, so i was unable see those images.

The **`python manage.py collectstatic`** did the work.